# How to remove text after a specific word in message in logstash using grok and gsub

Tags: logstash-grok

> "0x10022924 0x1027b06c 0x1027b118 0x1003c0 0xf99f358 0xf9a4040
>   0xf99f440 0x10281580 0x1027e964 0x100419e0 0x10041c04 0x10047d38
>   0x10052c5c 0x1007274c 0xfe88b08 0xfa372a8 Crash Debug Info:
>   airvCellStartRcvdTime_g = 0.000000000 airvCellStopDelRcvdTime_g =
>   0.000000000 Crash time at

I want drop everything starting form Crash

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To check basic GROK expression against your logs use this website: [GrokConstructor](http://grokconstructor.appspot.com).
For your data The required expression will be

```
^%{DATA:clientip} Crash %{GREEDYDATA:response}
```

where in response you will get the desired output:

```
Debug Info: airvCellStartRcvdTime_g = 0.000000000 airvCellStopDelRcvdTime_g = 0.000000000 Crash time at
```

Comment: thanks @anand tripathi, i wanted store little bit different data but it worked fine.